# awk get fields in multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a mobility file from ns2 and I want to extract the nodes coordinates at different intervals in different files.
To be more clear, if my file looks like this

```
cat mob.tcl
$node_(0) set X_ 656.02
$node_(0) set Y_ 1819.19
$node_(0) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) setdest 656.02 1819.19 0.00"
$ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(0) setdest 654.99 1818.19 1.44"
$node_(1) set X_ 365.41
$node_(1) set Y_ 1284.31
$node_(1) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(1) setdest 365.41 1284.31 0.00"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(0) setdest 652.74 1816.04 3.12"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(1) setdest 365.7 1281.79 2.54"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(0) setdest 649.08 1812.52 5.08"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(1) setdest 366.2 1277.44 4.37"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(0) setdest 643.59 1807.23 7.62"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(1) setdest 366.88 1271.47 6.01"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(0) setdest 636.46 1800.37 9.90"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(1) setdest 367.78 1263.63 7.90"
```

what I want to have is like 5 files time_1, time_2 ... time_5 each having the node id, x coordinate and y coordinate, for example time_1 will have

```
1 365.41 1284.31
```

what I managed to do so far is get the fields with awk like this

```
cat mob.tcl | awk -F'[_ ()]' '{print $4 "\t" $7 "\t" $10 "\t" $11}'
```

but then

1. I want to separate the fields extracted depending on what the line starts with

   if I try

   ```
   cat mob.tcl | awk '/$ns_/' -F'[_ ()]' '{print $4 "\t" $7 "\t" $10 "\t" $11}'
   ```

   to process only line starting with $ns_, I get an error
2. I want to put these fields in different files based on $4 value, so it should be a for loop but I don't see how I should write it (I am not sure what is the right syntax either with awk.

what i wrote so far is

```
 cat testAwk | awk '
 BEGIN { FS="[_() ]"}
 {
 if ($1 == "$node") 
    {
       print $3 "\t" $8 ;
    } else if ($1 == "$ns") {
       print  $7 "\t" $10 "\t" $11 ;
       time=5;
       for (i = 1; i <= time; i++)
       {   if ($4==i)
           {print  $7 "\t" $10 "\t" $11 >> "Time"$i}
       }
   } 

 }
```

but the files "Time"$i are not created correctly

Comment: i found it, i had to put '"time"i' instead of "time"$i

Comment: In the sample code, are duplicate lines being printed to stdout for debugging purposes only or are they desired output?  The question as stated only asks about writing to named files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the desired output to named files, this should do the trick:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 == "$ns_" && $3 > 0 {
    time=$3
    split($4, node, /[()]/)
    print node[2], $6, $7 >> "Time" int(time)
}' file
$ for f in Time*; do echo $f; cat $f; done
Time1
0       654.99  1818.19
1       365.41  1284.31
Time2
0       652.74  1816.04
1       365.7   1281.79
Time3
0       649.08  1812.52
1       366.2   1277.44
Time4
0       643.59  1807.23
1       366.88  1271.47
Time5
0       636.46  1800.37
1       367.78  1263.63
```

Notice the loop has been removed as it caused unnecessary iterations on each line.

And since the question as stated is about printing to named files, this code (unlike the question's sample code) does not print any duplicate lines to stdout.

Finally, [cat is not needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) with awk commands.

Comment: i was trying with `awk - f file` but it did not work so had to use cat. Can you explain to me why you used node[2]

Comment: One more thing, here the nodes are already sorted  but in the real file they are not necessarily. Is there a way to sort them in the resulting files?

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) solution:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
$node_(@node) set X_ @x
$node_(@node) set Y_ @y
@  (or)
$ns_ at @nil "$node_(@node) setdest @x @y @nil
@  (end)
@  (output `Time@node` :append)
@node @x @y
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Note: this results in some duplicate data from the `$node` and `$ns` entries. It is not necessary to process the `$node` entries.

Run:

```
$ rm Time*
$ txr node-xyz.txr data
$ ls Time*
Time0  Time1
$ cat Time0
0 656.02 1819.19
0 656.02 1819.19
0 654.99 1818.19
0 652.74 1816.04
0 649.08 1812.52
0 643.59 1807.23
0 636.46 1800.37
$ cat Time1
1 365.41 1284.31
1 365.41 1284.31
1 365.7 1281.79
1 366.2 1277.44
1 366.88 1271.47
1 367.78 1263.63
```

To process just the `$ns` material, we can strip out the `@(cases)` block:

```
@(repeat)
$ns_ at @nil "$node_(@node) setdest @x @y @nil
@  (output `Time@node` :append)
@node @x @y
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Comment: I don't get your code with all these @; what do they refer to ?

Comment: @etudiant_is `@` delimits pattern-matching variables and directives from text. Text matches itself. Variables capture material between text. Directives do various useful things like collection, repetition, output and whatnot. `@nil` is a special match which consumes and ignores something.   `$ns at @nil "$node_(@node) setdest @x @y @nil` matches a line in the input, and binds interesting pieces to variables:  The `node` variable gets the node number string, and `x` and `y` get the white-space delimited pieces after `setdest`. The `$ns at` and `"$node` and whatnot represent themselves.